# Euler's recursive algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I've been trying for a couple of days to solve a problem about Euler's function.
I have to come up with one which works like this:

```
float f_euler(int n)
f_euler(0)=2
f_euler(1)=2+ (2/2)=3
f_euler(2)=2+ 2/(2+ 3/3)= 2.6666…
f_euler(5)=2+ 2/(2+ 3/(3+ 4/(4+ 5/(5+6/6)))))= 2.7184…
```

etc...

This code is in C language.

Please! I would be really glad if someone helped me, I'm desperate! D:

Thanks :)

Question 1.1:

I finaly make this algorith but i'm not really sure if it will work :

f(n,i):

- i+1                                if  i=n
- 2                                  if i=0 && n=0
- 2+(2/(f(i+1))                      if   i=0 && n>0
- f((i+1)+((i+2)/f(i+1)))            if  i>0

Sorry if I 'm not explaining myself clearly but I'm new in this website.

Thanks you all!

Comment: Can you show your attempt at source code for `f_euler`? What you are showing here doesn't make sense from a C perspective.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should provide your attempt, as well documented as possible. More better you show what you have done, more likely you will get helped.

Comment: this line: 2+ 2/2=3 is not reasonable C code.  it is saying to make an assignment to 2/2 (which is not an lvalue) with the value 3,  The following lines have this same problem.  The compiler should have raised a warning/error and failed to compile the file.  Do you have all warnings/errors enabled?  in gcc, a parameter such as -Wall would have caught this problem.  Did you ignore the messages from the compiler?

Comment: f_euler(2)=2+ 2/(2+ 3/3)= 2.6666... This kind of sentences are just examples of how the code must work if we put number instead of n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a programming perspective, I think you are approaching this backwards.  Instead of recursing inwards, think about starting from the bottom and computing upwards.  Starting with your example:

```
float f_euler(int n)
f_euler(0)=2
f_euler(1)=2+ (2/2)=3
f_euler(2)=2+ 2/(2+ 3/3)= 2.6666…
f_euler(5)=2+ 2/(2+ 3/(3+ 4/(4+ 5/(5+6/6)))))= 2.7184…
```

We can rewrite the steps of `f_euler(5)` as a series of updates

```
val = 6
val = 5 + 6/val
val = 4 + 5/val
val = 3 + 4/val
val = 2 + 3/val
val = 1 + 2/val
```

The pattern and how it should translate to a loop should be a lot clearer from this 
representation.

Note that the last line should be `2 + 2/val`, but you can add another unit before returning; this shows the loop structure more clearly.

Comment: Thanks you so much, now I have to see the exception of the first interaction and the last one. But now I see it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try decomposing the problem into

```
Approximation = Starting approximation + Error Correction
```

then you can represent it recoursively as

```
Approximation(call N) = Approximation(call N - 1) + Error Correction
```

And finally write a C function that looks like

```
float approximation = getApproximation(oldApproximation, other items...);
```

since the error correction can be computed from the "other items"

Comment: This is just an intermediate step.  But it is needed before you can approach the recursive part, which would include embedding the approximation function into itself, and adding a "how many times to call" parameter.